# Different IDs for each appended child?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JavaScript and HTML and am not sure if this is even possible: can you create a different ID for each new appended child.

```
function myFunction() {
        var blank = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
        blank.id = "blank1";
        document.body.appendChild(blank);
      }
```

Each time I press my button it executes myFunction() but the new textarea has the same "blank1" ID, how do I make it so each new ID is "blank2' then "blank3' and so on.

Comment: attach a timestamp after `blank` for example or a random number...

Comment: But how would that be sequential @ths? The desired result is `blank1`, `blank2`, `blank3` etc., not a random number.

Comment: @JackBashford he could use a counter for that.

Comment: Yes, I know - see my answer. I'm just specifying that the suggestion in your comment is incorrect because it will not provide the desired output.

Comment: @JackBashford Honestly I didn't read the question I saw only the title.

Comment: Incrementing id's is most often not needed and using common classes for similar elements is all that is needed

Comment: Is there a reason why you want each dynamically appended element to have its own ID? As others have said, you can accomplish this by having some `counter` variable and increment this as you append more items. However, why are you needing each element to have its own ID in the first place? This might be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter and increment it:

```
let counter = 0;
function myFunction() {
  var blank = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
  blank.id = "blank" + ++counter;
  document.body.appendChild(blank);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the count of how many textareas are on the page

```
function myFunction() {
     var blank = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
     blank.id = "blank1" + document.querySelectorAll('textarea').length;;
     document.body.appendChild(blank);
   }
```

To be more specific you can add the same class to all textareas and then check

```
function myFunction() {
    var blank = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
    blank.class = "textarea-count";
    blank.id = "blank1" + document.querySelectorAll('textarea.textarea-count').length;;
    document.body.appendChild(blank);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will not only set incrementally suffixed ids, it will create any number (**`Param4: extra`**) of the same tag (**`Param2: tag`**) and append them to any element ( **`Param1: selector`** ) and set any attribute (**`Param3.0: cfg[0]`**) given and suffix each attribute value (**`Param3.1: cfg[1]`**) with an incremented index number. If there are pre-existing siblings of the same tag, they will be included in the process as well. There is also an option to forego the suffixing of attribute values as well (**`Param3.2: cfg[2]`**). The return is an array of all of the tags. I created this function to be versatile in case when the time comes when it is realized that ids aren't really needed.

**Details commented in demo**
**The checkbox will hide/show the console**

```js
/** attrSeries()
@Params: selector [string]: CSS selector of parent
         tag [string]: Name of elements to target/create
         cfg [array]: cfg[0] [string]: Name of attribute
                      cfg[1] [string]: Base value of attribute
                      cfg[2] [boolean]: if true suffix an 
                                        incremented index number
                                        to each Base
         extra [number]: default: 0 -- Number of tags to create.
This function will first create any number of tags and append them 
to a given element. Next it will collect all tags within that
element and assign each tag a given attribute and value. It will 
also suffix each attribute value with an index number optionally.
//A Reference the parent tag
//B if extra is 1 or more...
//C on each loop create a tag and append it to parent
//D Collect all target tags within parent into a NodeList and 
    convert that into an array
//E for...of loop on the entries of array, destructure each 
    element of the array into entries of index and node
//F if the 3rd element of cfg array is true...
    value is  2nd element of cfg array + index+1...
    otherwise value is 2nd element of cfg array
//G Set current node attribute named by the value of the 
    1st element of cfg array.
//H Return the array of nodes
*/
function attrSeries(selector, tag, cfg, extra = 0) {
  const parent = document.querySelector(selector); //A
  if (extra > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < extra; i++) {
      let node = document.createElement(tag);
      parent.appendChild(node);
    }
  }
  const nodes = [...parent.querySelectorAll(tag)];
  for (let [index, node] of nodes.entries()) {
    let value = cfg[2] ? cfg[1] + (index + 1) : cfg[1];
    node.setAttribute(cfg[0], value);
  }
  return nodes;
}

let cfg0 = ['id', 'blank', true];
console.log(attrSeries('.grp1', 'textarea', cfg0, 3));

let cfg1 = ['type', 'number', false];
console.log(attrSeries('.grp2', 'input', cfg1));

let cfg2 = ['class', 'btn', false];
let cfg3 = ['type', 'button', false];
let cfg4 = ['id', 'b', true];
console.log(attrSeries('.grp3', 'button', cfg2, 6));
console.log(attrSeries('.grp3', 'button', cfg3));
console.log(attrSeries('.grp3', 'button', cfg4));

// For demo purposes
document.getElementById('console').onchange = function(e) {
  let status = this.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
  document.querySelector('.as-console-wrapper').style.display = status;
}
```

```html
Enable Console <input id='console' type='checkbox' checked>
<fieldset class='grp1'>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <textarea></textarea>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class='grp2'>
  <input type='number'>
  <input type='text'>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class='grp3'>
  <button></button>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use an Immediately Invoked Function Expression or [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to define your custom function. The advantage of this approach is that you end up with two execution block: one which is executed once (which is perfect to initialize and remember a counter) and the second which will be executed every time the custom function is called.

Consider the following example, the resulting code is not too far from your original code:

```js
var myFunction = (function() {
  // This portion will only be executed once
  var counter = 1;
  
  // This function will called everytime myFuction() is call
  return function() {
    var blank = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
    blank.id = 'blank' + counter;    
    document.body.appendChild(blank);

    // For visual demonstration purpose only
    blank.placeholder = blank.id
    
    // Increment counter
    counter++;
  }
})();
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Add Text Box</button>
```